# How to get object of specific page in Grav plugin

Tags: plugins, grav

I've tried a lot of ways, but without success

For example

```
use Grav\Common\Page\Pages;

public function onPagesInitialized()
{
    $pages = $this->grav['pages'];
    print_r($pages->get('/about'));
    // or
    print_r($pages->find('/about', true));
}
```

returns nothing

The plugin of flex objects is enabled

---

**EDITED**

Adding the function `onPluginsInitialized()` with enabling `onPagesInitialized()` also doesn't help:

```
public function onPluginsInitialized(): void
{
    $this->enable([
        'onPagesInitialized' => ['onPagesInitialized', 0],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The statements "without success" and "returns nothing" are quite ambiguous. The function as is shouldn't return anything indeed. If you mean nothing is being printed, it could be function 'onPagesInitialized' isn't being called, or the page hasn't been found. Did you check this in the debugger?

Comment: @passerby I've added edit to the question

Comment: If I use debugger and `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`, I receive NULL

Comment: What does the file path to /about look like?

Comment: Is the request made by Admin?

Comment: Please share in what way the solution you selected solved your issue

Comment: I tried to get page object at the /admin/ side and didn't know we need to call `$this->grav['admin']->enablePages()` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a sample of how one can get a specific page object.

When using the following folder structure: (from Blog skeleton)

```
user/pages
└── 01.blog
    ├── blog.md
    ├── ...
    ├── hero-classes
    │   ├── item.md
    │   └── unsplash-overcast-mountains.jpg
    ├── london-at-night
    │   ├── item.md
    │   ├── unsplash-london-night.jpg
    │   └── unsplash-xbrunel-johnson.jpg
    └── ...
```

Assuming event 'onPagesInitialized' has been subscribed to, the following code correctly returns the sought pages:

```
public function onPagesInitialized(Event $event) {
    /** @var Pages */
    $pages = $event['pages']; // or $this->grav['pages'];

    $p1 = $pages->find('/blog');
    $p2 = $pages->find('/blog/london-at-night');
    $p3 = $pages->find('/blog/hero-classes');
}
```

**Note:**
When the request is made by plugin Admin, pages will not be initialized. One needs to call `$this->grav['admin']->enablePages();` first.

```
public function onPagesInitialized(Event $event) {
    $this->grav['admin']->enablePages();

    /** @var Pages */
    $pages = $event['pages']; // or $this->grav['pages'];

    $p1 = $pages->find('/blog');
    $p2 = $pages->find('/blog/london-at-night');
    $p3 = $pages->find('/blog/hero-classes');
}
```